# One-line trick in Python 3.* for a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.*, is there a way to achieve the same results by using one line?

```
feature_combo = [(i,icol) for i,icol in enumerate(keepCols) if icol in features]
feature_id = [i[0] for i in feature_combo]
feat_name = [i[1] for i in feature_combo]

## where keepCols=['a','b','c','d',...,'z']; features = ['b', 'c', ... , 't']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
feature_id, feat_name = zip(*feature_combo)
```

Or completely in one line:

```
feature_id, feat_name = zip(*filter(lambda x: x[1] in features, enumerate(keepCols)))
```